# Excel VBA - Repeating Cell Range in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of cells that contain names, such as:

```
UBBR1
UBBR2
UESR1
UESR2
UDCR1
UDCR2
SBBR1
SBBR2
SESR1
SPDCR1
SPDCR2
SADCR1
GCCS-M DBM
SADCR2
SPDCR3
SCIBBR1
SCIDCR1
SVTCR1
```

The range of those cells is stored in a variant called mapping listed below.Into another sheet. The number of times these names get repeated depends on the number of rows that are in another sheet. Each name above has a unit number that is in its same row, I store in another variant called ddg. The unit numbers stored in ddg refer to the names of different sheets in this workbook where the tables of data I am using are stored. For example, 2 below refers to "Unit #2" which is a table that has 38 rows, so UBBR1(Above) would need to be repeated 38 times.

ddg:

```
2
2
61
64
11
14
4
4
61
16
14
16
42
18
19
9
20
51
```

Code:

```
ddg = ws.Range("E4:E21").Value
mapping = ws.Range("B4:B21").Value

For Each k In ddg
        m = "Unit #" & k
        lastN = Sheets("Test").Range("B50000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each i In mapping


       N = Cells(Sheets(m).Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 1 To N


        Sheets("Test").Range("B" & lastN).Value = i

        Next j


    Next i

Next k
```

Where i is a variant and mapping is also a variant that contains the range of the cells that contain the names. N is a long that gets row count of the sheet for the repetition. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the loop does not repeat the values instead it loops through everything in mapping, leaves that in the cell and does the same all the way down. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code, particularly where you assign `mapping`

Comment: You are overriding the value in `"B" & N` `j` times, always with the same value of `i`.  Can you provide expected results based on your given sample data?

Comment: Made the changes to the code

Comment: Why is Greg repeated 4 times but Julie only twice, and 5 Joe's ?

Comment: The number of times they are represented depends on the number of rows in the sheets those names correspond to. For example, Greg, represents a sheet that has 4 rows so it gets repeated 4 times.

Comment: What's the relationship between `mapping` and `ddg` (and what is `ddg`) ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Mapping contains the range of names in that sheet. ddg holds the range of cells that have the corresponding sheet numbers so the script knows which sheet to go to, to count rows.

Comment: Does each cell in `ddg` correspond to one single cell in `mapping`?  It would really help you get answers if you provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: I updated the original table with the actual data I am using. I was afraid to post it due to confidentiality but this stuff is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim ddg, mapping, k As Long,  N As Long
    Dim unitNum, nm

    '...
    '...

    ddg = ws.Range("E4:E21").Value
    mapping = ws.Range("B4:B21").Value

    For k = 1 To UBound(ddg, 1)

        unitNum = ddg(k, 1)
        nm = mapping(k, 1)

        With Sheets("Unit #" & unitNum)
            N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        Debug.Print N & " rows for Unit# " & unitNum & " (" & nm & ")" '<<<

        Sheets("Test").Range("B50000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                                      .Resize(N, 1).Value = nm

    Next k


End Sub
```

You only need one loop, and you can write all the values in one shot.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you! Only thing is it writes the values a few too many times (100 more). I'm trying to tinker with it to see why that is.

Comment: It's possible I'm still misunderstanding your process.

Comment: Probably, it's hard to explain it online without showing you everything. But assume, in ddg unit 2 has 38 rows. the script should be able to count the 38 rows and then write UBBR1 38 times and then move to the next item and do the same. It does this now but just too many times.

Comment: See my added Debug.Print - take a look at the output (in the Immediate pane) and see if anything looks off

Comment: Yeah, seems as though all the totals for the rows are off. For example, UBBR1 has "329 rows for Unit #2".

Comment: OH! seems as though it is counting empty rows, as well. That's why the numbers are off

Comment: Seems like those rows aren't really empty?  End(xlUp) should do exactly the same as Ctrl+up and take you to the last used cell in ColA.  Try it out and check what's in that cell.

Comment: Oddly enough ctl + up takes me to that last item which is what I need. Could it be because these rows are part of a table, so it is just counting table rows, used or not?

Comment: I don't use tables that much, but on testing with a table, Ctrl+Up took me to the last row of the table, even though the column I was in had empty cells at the end. Even when the table has completely empty rows at the end Ctrl+Up takes you to the last table row (not the last *occupied* row).  End(xlUp) behavior was the same as using the keyboard. I didn't know about that so that's a useful bit of info for me...

Comment: I just deleted my empty rows because they come after my useful information and now it works like a charm. Thank you for all your help!